# ActiveRecord how to know if an instance model is into one of the class scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a scope defined in my ActiveRecord class, let's say:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :old, where( "published_at < ?", 1.year.ago )
end
```

I would like to ask to any instance of this class something like this:

```
book.old?
```

Is there any way to do this without duplicating the `where` definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run another query on the database, using your scope:

```
Book.old.exists?(book.id)
```

If you want to re-use this in multiple places, it would be better to implement a method:

```
def old?
  Book.old.exists?(id)
end

book.old?
```

Comment: You can do `Book.old.include?(book)`, but this loads and array and calls `#include?()` on that array, so performance would drop off with lots of records.

Comment: The `.include?` approach can't be accepted for the over-load that you mention

Comment: The `where(:id => book.id).any?` is a very good one.. I'd improve it like this `Book.old.exists?(self.id)`.. I'm updating your answer, let me know if you accept the modifications.

Comment: Yep, great! `exists?` seems so obvious now that someone else has written it. Thanks.